# Compare 2 Lists and Create New List with Different Items

Tags: c#, .net, list, .net-2.0

I have two Lists that I'm trying to compare.  What I need to accomplish is essentially to remove the items that are duplicated between the two lists and only keep the objects that are different.  Right now, I'm inserting the non-duplicate data into a new list.

The data I'm using here...

LIST1
("b",2)
("c",3)

LIST2
("a",1)
("b",2)
("c",3)
("d",4)

NEWLIST
("a",1)
("d",4)

Here's what I have so far...

My object:

```
public class TestClass
{
    protected string teststring;
    protected int testint;

    public string TestString
    {
        get { return teststring; }
        set { teststring = value; }
    }
    public int TestInt
    {
        get { return testint; }
        set { testint = value; }
    }

    public TestClass() { }
}
```

My compare logic:

```
private static List<TestClass> CompareCodes(List<TestClass> list1, List<TestClass> list2)
{
    List<TestClass> newList = new List<TestClass>();
    foreach (TestClass s in list2)
    {
        if (list1.Contains(s) == false)
        {
            newList.Add(s);
        }
    }        

    if (newList.Count != 0)
        return newList;
    else
        return null;
}
```

The new list will be used to insert data into a database table.  If it's null, no action will be taken.  I'm using .NET 2.0 in this app (it's an enhancement to an older app), so I can't use LINQ.  So is there any other way to make this work that I'm missing?  Or is there a better way to do this?  I haven't been able to find anything (maybe just not looking hard enough) to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There isn't any better way. Just remove the last `if` statement, `newList` will never be `null`, also, you must override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `TestClass`

Comment: Instead of removing that last `if` check, you should change the statement to look for `if (newList.Count != 0)`

Comment: I think that returning an empty list is better than returning null.

Comment: Yeah, I actually did that in my app after I posted this once I realized that.  So that part is already fixed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're almost there, but you'll need to override the `Equals` method on your class to make it work:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public override bool Equals(object y)
    {
        TestClass newY = y as TestClass;
        if (newY == null) { return false; }

        return newY.TestString == this.TestString &&
            newY.TestInt == this.TestInt;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
            int hash = 17;

            // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
            hash = hash * 23 + this.TestInt.GetHashCode();
            hash = hash * 23 + this.TestString == null ?
                0 :
                this.TestString.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Use [Jon Skeet's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode) to implement your hash code.

Comment: he is using .net 2.0 did you read the question var is in .net 3.0

Comment: @Ric, that interface is probably not available to the OP considering the version of the framework they are using (I'll check). But further, even with `IEquatable<T>` you need to implement these two methods.

Comment: @JulieShannon, yeah I read the question; that's why I didn't use LINQ. Using `var` is just a habit now.

Comment: I was only going for `IEquatable<T>` as there is only one method to implement, `Equals(T other)` so it's more generic etc. And it's available for .net 2 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms131190(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @Ric, I did notice it's available. But remember this, `IEquatable<T>` isn't enough. There isn't a huge adoption of consumers of that interface. You still need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud fair enough :)

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud so stupid question...how do I actually implement this into my CompareCodes function?  I was looking at something similar to what JulieShannon answered because I would have to get the object out of each list in order to compare them.  So my thought was "if(s.Equals(t))", or am I still missing something?

Comment: @LDWisdom take a look at my answer below that shows you how to merge that code into your TestClass

Comment: @LDWisdom, just literally paste the code I've provide into your class. Now, the `GetHashCode` implementation, you need to grab that from the Jon Skeet answer I provided. If you give me a couple minutes I can show you how it would fit into your class.

Comment: @LDWisdom, and you don't actually change the `CompareCodes` method. The problem with the `Contains` call is it will *always* return `false`. You have to *override* the equality operation for your class. The code I provided goes in the `TestClass`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud OK, this is starting to make more sense to me.  Thanks for the help!  I'll try this out and see how it works. :)

Comment: @MauricioGracia thanks for your help too!  Seeing it all out there helped it make more sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

In the code that you have provided you are only keeping the items of **list2** that are not in **list1**. but how about the items that are in **list1** but not in **list2** ? and since you mention

> What I need to accomplish is essentially to remove the items that are duplicated between the two lists and only keep the objects that are different

This code belows returns a new list with the items that are unique in both lists

```
private static List<TestClass> CompareCodes(List<TestClass> list1, List<TestClass> list2)
{
    List<TestClass> newList ;

    newList = new List<TestClass>();

    //All the items in list1 that are not in list2 are added
    foreach (TestClass s in list1)
    {
        if ( ! list2.Contains(s))
        {
            newList.Add(s);
        }
    }        

    //All the items in list2 that are not in list1 are added
    foreach (TestClass s in list2)
    {
        if ( ! list1.Contains(s))
        {
            newList.Add(s);
        }
    }        

    return newList;
}
```

And in your class

```
public class TestClass implements IEquatable
{
    protected string teststring;
    protected int testint;

    public string TestString
    {
        get { return teststring; }
        set { teststring = value; }
    }
    public int TestInt
    {
        get { return testint; }
        set { testint = value; }
    }
    public override bool Equals(object y)
    {
        TestClass newY = y as TestClass;
        if (newY == null) { return false; }
        return newY.TestString == this.TestString &&
            newY.TestInt == this.TestInt;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // use this example or implement some hash code logic
        return this.TestInt.GetHashCode() ;
    }
    public TestClass() { }
}
```

Comment: It will if the OP overrides the equality that is.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static List<TestClass> CompareCodes(List<TestClass> list1,
    List<TestClass> list2)
{
    List<TestClass> newList = new List<TestClass>();
    bool found = false; 
    foreach (TestClass s in list2)
    {
        foreach (TestClass t in list1)
        {   
           //let's say that teststring is your object id / key 
            if(s.TestString==t.TestString )
            { 
                found = true; 
                break; 
            }
        }

        if(!found)         
            newList.Add(s);               

       found=false;  
   }
  // do the something for the List1 
    foreach (TestClass s in list1)
    {
        foreach (TestClass t in list2)
        {   
           //let's say that teststring is your object id / key 
            if(s.TestString==t.TestString )
            { 
                found = true; 
                break; 
            }
        }

        if(!found)         
            newList.Add(s);               

       found=false;  
     }



   if (newList != null)
       return newList;
   else
       return null;
}
```